# Create a view like Tweetie's User Profile view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview

I'm just wondering if anyone has any idea on how you can create a view that looks like the user profile view in apps like Tweetie, where there are seemingly multiple tables with a couple of normal (straight up and down tables) and then two rows of six cells, which in Tweeties case have the number of followers, following etc.

I'm trying to make a similar view for my app, but can't seem to find out the best way to create it. Any tutorials, advice etc. would be appreciated.

Thanks.

P.S. Here's a **picture of the view which I'm trying to recreate.**

[alt text http://technopedia.info/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/tweetie22.jpg](http://technopedia.info/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/tweetie22.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

To get the same effect as Tweetie's split cell, create a custom cell and add a Segmented Control and create title and detail labels[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a grouped tableview using custom cells.  The image you show has two visible sections, and the top of a third.  It also has a custom table header view.  The second section has two cells built from four UILabels and a dividing line graphic in the middle.  You can create this in a nib, or by hand.

You can even change the grey pin-stripe background if you want.